# What is UTM Zone 0?

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I am currently working with some roadway link data and it is being projected in UTM.
After importing the shapefile into GRASS I can view the map and it looks correct but when I view the projection values it does not make sense.

I am new to UTM and from what I've read, the projection ranges should not be negative?

```
 |         Projection: Universal Transverse Mercator (zone 0)                 |
 |               N:  3819419.55631945    S:   3790632.2916996                 |
 |               E:  -139393.68501688    W:  -175353.36149413                 |
```

As far as I am aware UTM zones range from 1 to 60...

My PRJ file says that the projection should be of `NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N` =>`GCS_North_American_1983`

So given GRASS's report and what my PRJ file specifies, is this correct?

I have also imported the shapefile into postgreSQL and also get the same negative range of eastings.

Also, if they are correct I don't understand how to "go" to `-139393.68501688,3819419.55631945` on a map so I can verify that it's around where I expected it to be.

Comment: If the coordinates are referenced to zone 12 north, the extent's in Los Angeles county (which actually falls in zone 11 north).

Comment: How to I change their reference to zone 11?